# UK family permit for my wife to accompany me to visit our son in London

Tags: uk-visa

I'm a British citizen living in Nigeria, married to a Nigerian woman. We've been married for over 20 years, and have two 2 sons, aged 20 and 17. The 17-year-old is studying for his A levels in London. Can I get a UK family permit for my wife to accompany me on a trip to the UK to visit our son?

Answer (score 1):

For a visit of six months or shorter, she will need a Standard Visitor Visa. The EEA Family Permit is only applicable to the family of EU citizens who are exercising their freedom of movement rights under EU law.

Because you are returning from outside the EU to your country of citizenship, EU law is not implicated: you are exercising your right of abode under *domestic* law, and your accompanying family member will be covered by domestic law as well.